# Is there a way to get \filedate and \fileversion from \ProvidesPackage{} inside the package source file?

Tags: package-writing, latex-base

I like to `\typeout` a message showing my package's version and date. I know about `\GetFileInfo` but that apparently only works within a `.dtx` file. Is there a way to automatically extract `\filedate` and `\fileversion` from a package's `\ProvidesPackage{}` declaration? I'm currently just defining a version string and using that in `\typeout` but that means having to edit versions and dates twice in a file, which may be prone to error.

MWE package `littlepackage.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{littlepackage}[2020/11/26 v1.2.3 A simple demo package]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]

\newcommand*{\littlepackageversion}{v1.2.3 dated 2020/11/26}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\typeout{}
\typeout{littlepackage: You're using littlepackage version \littlepackageversion.}
\typeout{}
}%
```

MWE `littledemo.tex` document that uses the package:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{littlepackage}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `\usepackage` command already print the package's file info in the log?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes it does, but I obviously can't manipulate that programmatically.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think the `readprov` package gets pretty close to what you want. The only thing is that it inserts a `\relax` that also makes its way into the log.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you. I didn't know about that package. I will look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\ProvidesPackage{littlepackage}[2020/11/26 v1.2.3 A simple demo package]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]



\AtBeginDocument{%
\typeout{}
\typeout{littlepackage: You're using littlepackage version \csname ver@littlepackage.sty\endcsname}
\typeout{}
}%
```

Comment: It might be worth considering  a real interface for that one day